# Why is my ejs templates won't display properly?

Tags: javascript, node.js, path, ejs

I'm trying to display a web page and i'm constantly getting this error :

Could not find the include file "layouts/_header"

```
<%- include("layouts/_header") %>
<div class="container">    
    <div class="row justify-content">
        <div class="col-xl-12">
            <div class="mb-2">
                <h3>Ajouter variable</h3>
```

I also included this path `app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "views"));` so i can shorten the call outs. I don't know if it changes anything but I'm using a route file and a controller before displaying the view.

Here is my file architecture:

- views

  - layouts

    - _header.ejs
    - _footer.ejs
  - variables

    - variables.ejs

Comment: Could you please provide more info about this error? Like your folder structure and also could you please provide us with a better error message.

Comment: I changed it hope it's better

Comment: did you set `view engine` for `ejs`?  add this instead `<%- include('./layouts/_header.ejs'); %>` and post your code instead of posting a `link` or an `image` so, that it may help you to get a better solution and not downvote probably.

Comment: thanks for the advises tho. i posted the answer i found

Comment: If you guys could also upvote my answer so i can reach 50 popularity points, and finally give comments to other posts, it would be nice. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was a wrong path call.

The call i had was `<%- include("layouts/_header") %>`

but it needed to be called `<%- include("../layouts/_header") %>`

because my view named "variable.ejs" is placed in a subfolder of view.

- views

  - layouts

    - _header.ejs
    - _footer.ejs
  - variables

    - variables.ejs

So paths are not made according to where your index.js (the file where you start your server) is located but where your current file is.